Did Oppenheimer comment about the split between Dr. Tsung Dao Lee and Dr. Chen Ning Yang?
Tsung-Dao Lee, who in 1957 became the second-youngest scientist to receive a Nobel Prize passed away on August 4
The story of his breakup with his co-recipient of the 1957 Nobel Prize, Yang Chen Ning becomes a trending topic(again) in China.
Many Chinese articles said Oppenheimer commented about the split as "李政道应该不要再做高能物理，而杨振宁应该去看看精神医生", roughly translated as "T. D. Lee should stop doing high-energy physics, and C. N. Yang should go see a psychiatrist."
It was said that Oppenheimer made this comment when Tsung-Dao Lee submitted his resignation to him because of the split.
I quote one article here called 李政道与杨振宁恩怨始末. The title is roughly translated as "the history of the split between them". The article was published in a magazine called "瞭望东方周刊" run by The People's Daily, the official newspaper of the CCP.
Try as I may I can't find out whether Oppenheimer did say those words.
If I google the whole Chinese sentence, I will get many results. But since I can't find the English version of that, all those results seem fishy.
Oppenheimer did hold both of them in high regard, e.g. check https://www.ias.edu/ website, Celebrating Chen Ning Yang at 100 and Tsung Dao Lee


Please link the article(s) making this claim.

You still need to link to a specific article containing the claim. Simply saying "there are lots of results on Google" isn't good enough; it's your responsibility as the question-asker to demonstrate notability, not our responsibility to go tracking down a copy of the claim you're making.

For the "history of the split" article, which does seem to be a notable source, can you please translate the passage from the article that contains the claim, including any relevant context?

Additionally, besides the link and title of the article, please include a full citation (in English): full name of the magazine, name of the author, date of publication.

If I have those information I don't need to ask the question at all.

If you don't know about the history of them (not the split), you may check this article https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1962/05/12/a-question-of-parity

@Qiulang: You have done a Google search, and given us a screenshot of the results so we can't click it. Instead, do a Google search, find the best 2 or 3 examples, and give us the URLs. It would be best if you also included the name of the web-site, when they were published, and include an excerpt (with translation) so we could see that they made the claim.

@Oddthinking After doing my research (even before I asked the question) I tend to believe this is a false quote. This also one of reasons I first asked the question at https://history.stackexchange.com/ but I deleted my question there and asked here.
